# How to add list of contact in Exchange server using EWS api?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am able to add contact one at a time but I want a list of contact to be added in a single service call. Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ExchangeService's "createItems()" method, passing a list of contacts you want to create

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it.

```
Collection<Item>  items = new ArrayList<Item>();
try
    {
        for (ContactDTO contactDTO : contactDTOList) {



            Contact contact=  new Contact(service);


            contact.setFileAs(contactDTO.getFirstName()+" FileAs");
            contact.setBusinessHomePage(contactDTO.getHomePageUrl());

            contact.setGivenName(contactDTO.getFirstName());
            contact.setSurname(contactDTO.getLastName());
            contact.setJobTitle(contactDTO.getTitle());
            contact.getEmailAddresses().setEmailAddress(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, new EmailAddress(contactDTO.getEmailId()));
            contact.getPhoneNumbers().setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumberKey.MobilePhone, contactDTO.getMobile());

            contact.getPhoneNumbers().setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone, contactDTO.getOfficePhoneNumber());

            items.add(contact);

        }
        MessageDisposition messageDispositon = MessageDisposition.SaveOnly ;
        SendInvitationsMode sendInvitationMode = SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone;
        service.createItems(items,FolderId.getFolderIdFromWellKnownFolderName(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts), messageDispositon, sendInvitationMode);
```